# Expected Value of cumulative distribution function

Tags: normal-distribution, expected-value, cumulative-distribution-function, approximation

Let $\varepsilon$ be a Gaussian distributed random variable with mean $\mu_0$ and standard deviation $\sigma_0$. Is it possible to compute/approximate the expected value

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
& &\mathbb{E}\left[\Phi\left(\frac{\varepsilon-\mu_1}{\sigma_1}\right)\mid\varepsilon<c\right]=...\\
& &... =\int_{-\infty}^{c}d\varepsilon \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\,\pi\,\sigma_0^2}}\,\exp\left(-\frac{\left(\varepsilon-\mu_0\right)^2}{2\,\sigma_0^2}\right)\,\int_{-\infty}^{\frac{\varepsilon-\mu_1}{\sigma_1}}dt\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\,\pi}}\,\exp\left(-\frac{t^2}{2}\right)  ?
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Note that while the integral

$$\int \exp\left(-x^2\right)\,\textrm{erf}\left(x\right)\,dx$$
exists (check on http://integrals.wolfram.com/index.jsp), any integral of the kind

$$
\int \exp\left(-(x-a)^2/b\right)\,\textrm{erf}\left((x-c)/d\right)\,dx
$$
does not exist (at least according to Wolfram integrals).

Comment: You seem to use "exist" in the sense of "has a conventional closed-form expression." ("Exist" in math and stats usually means that it has a well-defined value, whether or not that value can easily be written.) This raises the question of what you mean by "compute": are you looking for a closed-form expression, or would alternatives (such as a power series, and algorithm, or a numerical approximation) be acceptable?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I meant, the close-form expression seems to be not available, hence I am looking for something to approximate the integral, such as power series. In fact I have found something that can be helpful:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_expansions_for_the_moments_of_functions_of_random_variables